# Nginx doesn't listen on specified port

Tags: nginx, linode

I've set up and deployed a rails application using unicorn and nginx on linode. However when I go to the URL I've set in the applications config in sites-enable I am served with the default site that is listening on port 80. 
If I got to the IP and port I don't get anything at all. 
If I set the site to listen on 80 it works

The URL is pointing from the registrar to the linode IP and is working correctly.

xxxx.co.uk file in sites-enabled

```
upstream unicorn
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.xxxx.co.uk.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  server_name xxxx xxxx;
  listen 3001 default deferred;
  root /var/www/apps/nocn.org.uk/current/public;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    #try $uri /old$uri
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
  location @unicorn {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://unicorn;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 4G;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled remote access to port 3001 in linode's firewall or config?

Comment: Nope that was exactly the problem, feel free to submit it as an answer and I'll accept. It's still ignoring the alternate URL though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you enabled remote access to port 3001 in linode's firewall or config (by using iptables probably).

Comment: iptables was only set to allow 80 and 443, the URL specified in the server_name still gets caught by the default site though